# can't get value from .range.value

Tags: excel, vba

Im pulling data from 2 tables, one works as i expected. but the other one, same code, wont work. I just dont get it. Everything seems to be identical.
I've isolated the "find" and they return the correct line numbers on both tables.

The problem is that the loCustomerTable doesnt seem to have anything in the .value
Debug.print does a line feed, thats it.
no errors generated.

Why? What am I missing?

```
    Dim rProjectInfo As range
    Dim rCustomerInfo As range
    Dim loCustomerTable As ListObject
    Dim loProjectTable As ListObject
   
    Set loProjectTable = Worksheets("projektinformation").ListObjects("tblProjektinformation")
    Set loCustomerTable = Worksheets("kundinfo").ListObjects("tblKundInformation")
    
    sProjectNumber = "20-130"
    
    ' read project information
    Set rProjectInfo = loProjectTable.range.rows((loProjectTable.range.Columns(1).Find(sProjectNumber).row))
    ' get customer info base off project info.
    Set rCustomerInfo = loCustomerTable.range.rows((loCustomerTable.range.Columns(2).Find("gateau").row))
    
    Debug.Print rProjectInfo.Cells(, 1).Value
    Debug.Print rCustomerInfo.Cells(, 2).Value
```

Comment: I expected to get the complete row from the .find into the rcustomerinfo. and then reference each column to popluate a few textboxes with data. column 1, 2 etc.

Comment: Try `debug.print rCustomerInfo.range.address` and report the result. @FaneDuru - it doesn't make any difference if a single-row range.

Comment: SJR, that wont compile. "Argument not optional".

Comment: Let me guess: Your first table starts in Row 1 while the second starts below that?

Comment: Sorry should be `debug.print rCustomerInfo.address`.

Comment: A bit strange that `range`, `rows`, `row` are all lower case. Do you have other code?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are a victim of your monster statements (I don't get it why such statements are not split into smaller pieces so that you can easily debug it).

So let us split the statement

```
Set rCustomerInfo = _ 
 loCustomerTable.range.rows((loCustomerTable.range.Columns(2).Find("gateau").row))
```

First thing you do is fetch the table column

```
dim tabCol as Range
set tabCol = loCustomerTable.range.Columns(2)
Debug.Print tabCol.Address
```

Check if the address is correct (should by). Now you search for your string ("gateau") in that column

```
dim rGateau as Range, row as long
set rGateau = tabCol.Find("gateau")
row = rGateau.Row
Debug.Print rGateau.Address, rGateau.Value2, row
```

That gives you the address of the cell with the search string (code assumes that this string can always be found), and its row number.

Now what you will see it that the row number is the row within the sheet, not within the table (listObject) - but you use it as row number within your table. If the table does not start at row 1, you are now reading data from the wrong row (which might even be below the table).
What you can do it either consider the start of your table or intersect the table with the row where you found the name.

```
' Variant 1: Calculate the row number within the table
row = rGateau.Row - loCustomerTable.Range.Row + 1
Set rCustomerInfo = loCustomerTable.Range.Rows(row)

' Variant 2: Intersect the (sheet) row with the table
row = rGateau.Row
Set rCustomerInfo = Intersect(loCustomerTable.Parent.Rows(row), loCustomerTable.Range)

Debug.Print rCustomerInfo.address
```

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sure thing, I mentioned that in my answer, but this was obviously not the problem of the OP. Kudos++ for Rubberduck

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! great help and insight. One of the things i struggle with is code structure. How to make things easy to read etc. This is abviously on of those instances. Thanks a lot for the sollution! regarding the error 91, took it out before posting since it wasnt part of the "error".